# Looking for Video streaming in ios using Wowza Media Server

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, wowza

I want to know how can I develop a app of video streaming for iphone, in which two users and a group can video chat using Wowza media server ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mobile application using [adobe air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile-development-flex-flashbuilder.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_1). Based on that just code a regular video chat application using `NetConnection` and `NetStream`, there are a lot of tutorials over the web about it.